# Maximal linearly independent subsets problem.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand the proof of the following theorem:

Let $S$ be a linearly independent subset of a vector space $V$, then there exists a maximal linearly independent subset of $V$ that contains $S$.

We consider a collection say $G$ which contains all the linearly independent sets of $V$ that contain $S$.

So, $G$ could be represented as $\{S_1,S_2,S_3......\}$, where $S_i$ is a linearly independent subset of V containing $S$.

Now we consider a 'chain' $X$ in $G$ which itself is a collection of sets such that for any $A,B \in X$ either $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$.

Now, we claim that there exists some $U \in G$ where $U$ is the union of all the elements in $X$.

So, $U$ is the union of all the elements of $X$, whose elements contain $S$, so certainly, $S \subseteq U$.

Now we need to prove that $U$ is linearly independent.

$(*)$ Say, $\{u_1,u_2,.....,u_n\}$ be elements in $U$, for some scalars consider $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_iu_i)=0$.

Now, $u_i \in U$ which is the union of all the elements of $X$, so, $u_i \in A$ where $A$ is some set in $X$.

Since, $X$ is a chain, there exists a bigger set $B$ such that $u_i \in B$, in fact all $u_i$'s are in $B$.

Now, $B \in X\subseteq G$ and hence $B$ is linearly independent so the scalars are zero and hence according to the maximal principle, we have a maximal linearly independent subset containing $S$.

The problem is, where are we assuming that there are only a finite number of elements in $U$ in the $(*)$ statement above ?

We are proving this kind of theorems to be able to extend the results done earlier with finite dimensional vector spaces to infinite dimensional vector spaces, so we cannot assume $V$ to be finite dimensional, can we ?

Also, if we assume that there are only a finite number of elements in $U$, that would mean finite elements in the chain $X$ and that would imply finite elements in the set $S$, which could be false for an infinite dimensional vector space ?

Is that even a valid question ?

Please help !

Comment: $U$ is just the biggest element of $X$ no? and elements of $X$ are elements of $G$. no?

Comment: That's right.@Dror

Comment: a maximal set of linearly independent vectors turns out to be a basis. Any other vector you add to it spoils it, hence it is a basis. Why does the non-finite case bother you here?

Comment: My point is, by saying $U$ has finite elements, aren't we concluding that $V$ is finite dimensional ?

Comment: Why must it be finite? I don't follow

Comment: I want to portray that statement  in a different manner, $U$ could have infinite elements too, couldn't it ?

Comment: I don't see why not. the chain $X$ can be just adding another vector each step. If you prove that it remains linearly independent in the scheme of $X$ then you can go on and on, and that's pretty much how I know an infinite basis is built/defined.

Comment: Umm.. I think it's gonna take a while to accept the proof I guess. But thanks anyway for your help ! @Dror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should't use enumerations such as $G=\{S_1,S_2,S_3,\dotsc\}$, because the set $G$ could be much more than countable.

Anyway, this is not the main point. *A set of vectors is linearly independent if and only if every finite subset thereof is linearly independent.*

Recall that a linear combination of vectors in a possibly infinite sets is one where all but a finite number of coefficients is $0$.

Thus you are reduced to prove that any finite subset of $U$ is linearly independent, which is true, because the finite subset is contained in a single element of the chain and each element of the chain is linearly independent by construction.

There's no assumption on the space to be finite-dimensional.